# Heterozygous traits with advantages over homozygous traits

Tags: genetics

I used to believe that there are "good" alleles and "bad" alleles and having two "good" alleles could never be worse than having one "good" and one "bad" allele.

However with sickle sell anemia having one "good" and one "bad" allele confers stronger immunity against malaria (though it can also cause hematuria and other generally undesirable outcomes).

Are there any other examples of this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterozygote_advantage

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a rather common phenomenon called [overdominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdominance) or [heterozygote advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterozygote_advantage). It can be due to many reasons: the two alleles affecting the same phenotypic trait via different paths, the phenotypic train being due to interaction of many linked alleles, the alleles having multiplicative effect, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The heterozygotes may exhibit increased disease resistence. In case of sickle cell disease, the phenotype is related to the infectivity of plasmodium. In the heterozygotes, the infectious agent is less likely to propogate within red blood cells.

Interestingly, researchers have speculated that other alleles in human may confer disease resistence in the heterozygous condition but are detrimental in the homozygous state.

These include PKU(Phenylketonuria) an inborn error of metabolism, in which the heterozygous fetus may be resistent to miscarriage caused by a fungal toxin(Ochratoxin A), and Tay-Sachs disease, in which the heterozygotes may be resistant to Tuberculosis.

You may refer to given link for more details;
https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/evolution/educators/course/session7/explain_b_pop1.html